# How to test non-dojo javascript code with doh?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dojo, doh

doh is the dojo unit-testing framework.
I am trying to use doh to test a non-dojo javascript code, but i am facing the problem that doh seems intrusive and oblige me to use dojo.provide() in the tested js file(and the corresponding dojo.require() in the test js file).
I want the tested js file to be unmodified and dojo-agnostic.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution.

- simple/MyModule.js
- simple/tests/MyModuleTest.js

In the test file, just use:

```
dojo.provide("simple.tests.MyModuleTest");

dojo.require("doh.runner");

dojo.require("simple.MyModule",true);
```

as the js file is find by its name without the dojo.provide() module check

http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.2/dojo.require

Comment: This seems to include the file, but registers it as "not-a-module". Any attempt to call a function in the file results in "function is not defined". How did you call the javascript function you wanted to test?

Answer (score 0):

I think DOH does have a dependency on the Dojo loader (only).  Have you tried just defining the object which would normally be in the dojo.provide?  You might get away with that. Instead of doing

```
dojo.provide("mytests.mymodule")
```

try

```
mytests.mymodule={};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check this [alternative of dojo DOH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32263606/javascript-testing-framework-similar-to-dojo-doh/32263908#32263908). It is Dojo Foundation Project developed by SitePen.