# Javascript Testing framework similar to dojo DOH

Tags: javascript, testing, dojo, doh

Is there any framework in javascript similar to [dojo DOH](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/util/doh.html)?

I am looking for testing framework which is browser-based like dojo DOH, it provide support for both browsers and JS runtime environment.

In simple words, I am looking for:

> A simple browser-based graphical front end and runner file.

Why I am looking for other Testing unit instead of dojo DOH?

Dojo DOH come with complete package of DOJO, so if I develop an application in dojo then it good to use dojo DOH. Suppose I develop an application in other frameworks like Angular, Backbone etc.

Then only to test application I have to add complete dojo package with my application. (Please correct me if I am wrong, this assumption was made as per my experience on dojo)

Please guide me, if there is a possibility to test application using dojo DOH without adding complete dojo package.

Thanks Help!!

Answer (score 0):

SitePen replaced `DOH` with [Intern](https://theintern.github.io/). Intern is well-tailored-for but not-specific-to the Dojo Framework. You can test any JS framework'd app with it. Note, though, I haven't used either.

Aside, an SE Architect I work with came back recently from a conference in love with [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/), so you may look at it. They seem to be completely different approaches to testing, so take a gander and decide for yourself where your tastes lie.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'll try both and share my experience.